# Firestore SetOptions.mergeFields doesn't work

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to use `.set` on my document to set 2 values inside it, but it gives me this error

```
Field 'friendRequests' is specified in your field mask but not in your input data.
```

Error is triggered by this line in my code:

```
mCollRef.document(documentID).set(tempUser, SetOptions.mergeFields(fieldsToUpdate))
```

**Everything works fine when i'm not using** `SetOptions`, just `mCollRef.document(documentID).set(tempUser)`

What did i do wrong here?

My Code here:

```
mCollRef.whereEqualTo("userID", clickedUserID)
  .get()
  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

     if(task.isSuccessful()) {

       List<String> fieldsToUpdate = Arrays.asList("friendRequests", "friends");

       for(QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {

         User tempUser = document.toObject(User.class);

         tempUser.updateFriends(mUsersName, mUsersID, 1);
         tempUser.updateFriendRequests(myNoDotEmail, 2);
         String friendName = tempUser.getUserName();
         String documentID = document.getId();

         mCollRef.document(documentID).set(tempUser, SetOptions.mergeFields(fieldsToUpdate))
           .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
              @Override
              public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                Toast.makeText(FriendsActivity.this, "Friend Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

              }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                  Toast.makeText(FriendsActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
 });
```

It's worth pointing out that sometimes it works, like 1/10 it'll work just for no reason whatsoever and other 9 times it just doesn't

Comment: Clearly, the field friendRequests is missing in the key/value pair?

Comment: Your field is absent. Are you sure yo have the correct code?

Comment: Oh, right... i mean, field isn't missing, but it's empty after things i do in my code. I'll post the whole answer below, thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, turns out that error was caused by my code few lines above `SetOptions` call:

[image]

As you can see above, field `friendRequests` isn't empty, but i'm setting it empty with this code from the question `tempUser.updateFriendRequests(myNoDotEmail, 2);` and that when it shows an error. Everything works when there are 2 or more `friendRequests` and i delete one  of them, not leaving field completely empty.

Turns out `SetOptions.mergeFields` can't be called  to set nested maps inside documents to empty maps.

Comment: I had a similar problem. I was merging fields but the input data was missing a field. It was supposed to be an optional field. But turns out that when using mergeFields in SetOptions none of the fields you have specified there can be missing. So it is mandatory to do something like [ "fieldName" : null ] in the map.